# Three.js function applyQuaternion() messes up animation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, orbitcontrols

I am trying to implement a simple keyboard navigation in three.js where I listen to keyboards events and make the camera move according to which arrow key is pressed.

I use a very simple system to define the camera movement :

```js
if (this.back_pressed) {
  this.camera_local_movement.z = -CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
} else if (this.forward_pressed) {
  this.camera_local_movement.z = CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
} else {
  this.camera_local_movement.z = 0;
}

if (this.left_pressed) {
  this.camera_local_movement.x = -CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
} else if (this.right_pressed) {
  this.camera_local_movement.x = CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
} else {
  this.camera_local_movement.x = 0;
}
```

Then, I convert that movement with `applyQuaternion()` to have the camera's movement according to the scene :

```js
this.camera_global_movement = this.camera_local_movement.applyQuaternion(this.camera.quaternion);

this.camera.position.z += this.camera_global_movement.z;
this.controls.target.z += this.camera_global_movement.z;

this.camera.position.x += this.camera_global_movement.x;
this.controls.target.x += this.camera_global_movement.x;
```

The result then, was not quite what I expected because, when I press <kbd>UP</kbd>, **the camera doesn't go forward right away** but kind of **backs off a bit before going forward** and **the movement doen't stop as soon as I release the key** but stops after a delay. And the same thing happens when I press <kbd>DOWN</kbd>. The really strange thing, though, is that <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> and <kbd>LEFT</kbd> don't show that behavior at all.

I am guessing that the problem may have something to do with the `applyQuaternion()` function because when I comment out that line, everyhing works fine (the camera doesn't bounce back).

Is there any way I can fix my code in?

I uploaded the full code in [this branch of my repo](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test/tree/non-spaghetti) for anyone who wants to test it.

Thanks for anyone who wants to help.

The below snippet is a minimal version of my code but somehow, i couldn't make the key events to work here so you may have to copy the scripts and run them localy.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, stats;

const CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED = 15;
const LEFT_KEY = "ArrowLeft";
const RIGHT_KEY = "ArrowRight";
const UP_KEY = "ArrowUp";
const DOWN_KEY = "ArrowDown";
let forward_pressed = false;
let back_pressed = false;
let left_pressed = false;
let right_pressed = false;
let camera_local_movement = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
let camera_global_movement = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
let controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 400;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(0, -150, 0);
  scene.add(mesh);
  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(light);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1);
  scene.add(directionalLight);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  stats = new Stats();
  document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.keys = {
    LEFT: 'ArrowLeft', //left arrow
    UP: 'ArrowUp', // up arrow
    RIGHT: 'ArrowRight', // right arrow
    BOTTOM: 'ArrowDown' // down arrow
  }

  const key_is_down = (e) => {
    console.log(e.code);
    if (e.code === UP_KEY) {
      forward_pressed = true;
    }
    if (e.code === DOWN_KEY) {
      back_pressed = true;
    }
    if (e.code === LEFT_KEY) {
      left_pressed = true;
    }
    if (e.code === RIGHT_KEY) {
      right_pressed = true;
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", key_is_down, false);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.code === UP_KEY) {
      forward_pressed = false;
    }
    if (e.code === DOWN_KEY) {
      back_pressed = false;
    }
    if (e.code === LEFT_KEY) {
      left_pressed = false;
    }
    if (e.code === RIGHT_KEY) {
      right_pressed = false;
    }
  }, false);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  stats.update();
  controls.update();

  if (back_pressed) {
    camera_local_movement.z = CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
  } else if (forward_pressed) {
    camera_local_movement.z = -CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
  } else {
    camera_local_movement.z = 0;
  }

  if (left_pressed) {
    camera_local_movement.x = -CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
  } else if (right_pressed) {
    camera_local_movement.x = CAMERA_KEYBOARD_SPEED;
  } else {
    camera_local_movement.x = 0;
  }

  camera_global_movement = camera_local_movement.applyQuaternion(
    camera.quaternion
  );

  camera.position.z += camera_global_movement.z;
  camera.position.x += camera_global_movement.x;
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/r17/build/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

<script data-name="orbitControls.js">
  THREE.OrbitControls = function(object, domElement) {
    this.object = object;
    this.domElement = (domElement !== undefined) ? domElement : document;
    this.enabled = true;
    this.target = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.minDistance = 0;
    this.maxDistance = Infinity;
    this.minZoom = 0;
    this.maxZoom = Infinity;
    this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
    this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians
    this.minAzimuthAngle = -Infinity; // radians
    this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
    this.enableDamping = false;
    this.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    this.enableZoom = true;
    this.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
    this.enableRotate = true;
    this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    this.enablePan = true;
    this.keyPanSpeed = 7.0; // pixels moved per arrow key push
    this.autoRotate = false;
    this.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0; // 30 seconds per round when fps is 60
    this.enableKeys = true;
    this.keys = {
      LEFT: 37,
      UP: 38,
      RIGHT: 39,
      BOTTOM: 40
    };
    this.mouseButtons = {
      ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT,
      ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
      PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT
    };
    this.target0 = this.target.clone();
    this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
    this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;
    this.getPolarAngle = function() {
      return spherical.phi;
    };
    this.getAzimuthalAngle = function() {
      return spherical.theta;
    };
    this.saveState = function() {
      scope.target0.copy(scope.target);
      scope.position0.copy(scope.object.position);
      scope.zoom0 = scope.object.zoom;
    };
    this.reset = function() {
      scope.target.copy(scope.target0);
      scope.object.position.copy(scope.position0);
      scope.object.zoom = scope.zoom0;
      scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
      scope.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
      scope.update();
      state = STATE.NONE;
    };
    this.update = function() {
      var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
      var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(object.up, new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
      var quatInverse = quat.clone();
      var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
      var lastQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
      return function update() {
        var position = scope.object.position;
        offset.copy(position).sub(scope.target);
        offset.applyQuaternion(quat);
        spherical.setFromVector3(offset);
        if (scope.autoRotate && state === STATE.NONE) {
          rotateLeft(getAutoRotationAngle());
        }
        spherical.theta += sphericalDelta.theta;
        spherical.phi += sphericalDelta.phi;
        spherical.theta = Math.max(scope.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min(scope.maxAzimuthAngle, spherical.theta));
        spherical.phi = Math.max(scope.minPolarAngle, Math.min(scope.maxPolarAngle, spherical.phi));
        spherical.makeSafe();
        spherical.radius *= scale;
        spherical.radius = Math.max(scope.minDistance, Math.min(scope.maxDistance, spherical.radius));
        scope.target.add(panOffset);
        offset.setFromSpherical(spherical);
        offset.applyQuaternion(quatInverse);
        position.copy(scope.target).add(offset);
        scope.object.lookAt(scope.target);
        if (scope.enableDamping === true) {
          sphericalDelta.theta *= (1 - scope.dampingFactor);
          sphericalDelta.phi *= (1 - scope.dampingFactor);
        } else {
          sphericalDelta.set(0, 0, 0);
        }
        scale = 1;
        panOffset.set(0, 0, 0);
        if (zoomChanged ||
          lastPosition.distanceToSquared(scope.object.position) > EPS ||
          8 * (1 - lastQuaternion.dot(scope.object.quaternion)) > EPS) {
          scope.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
          lastPosition.copy(scope.object.position);
          lastQuaternion.copy(scope.object.quaternion);
          zoomChanged = false;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      };
    }();
    this.dispose = function() {
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel, false);
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);
      scope.domElement.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
    };
    var scope = this;
    var changeEvent = {
      type: 'change'
    };
    var startEvent = {
      type: 'start'
    };
    var endEvent = {
      type: 'end'
    };
    var STATE = {
      NONE: -1,
      ROTATE: 0,
      DOLLY: 1,
      PAN: 2,
      TOUCH_ROTATE: 3,
      TOUCH_DOLLY: 4,
      TOUCH_PAN: 5
    };
    var state = STATE.NONE;
    var EPS = 0.000001;
    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    var sphericalDelta = new THREE.Spherical();
    var scale = 1;
    var panOffset = new THREE.Vector3();
    var zoomChanged = false;
    var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var panDelta = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyStart = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
    var dollyDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

    function getAutoRotationAngle() {
      return 2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * scope.autoRotateSpeed;
    }

    function getZoomScale() {
      return Math.pow(0.95, scope.zoomSpeed);
    }

    function rotateLeft(angle) {
      sphericalDelta.theta -= angle;
    }

    function rotateUp(angle) {
      sphericalDelta.phi -= angle;
    }
    var panLeft = function() {
      var v = new THREE.Vector3();
      return function panLeft(distance, objectMatrix) {
        v.setFromMatrixColumn(objectMatrix, 0); // get X column of objectMatrix
        v.multiplyScalar(-distance);
        panOffset.add(v);
      };
    }();
    var panUp = function() {
      var v = new THREE.Vector3();
      return function panUp(distance, objectMatrix) {
        v.setFromMatrixColumn(objectMatrix, 1); // get Y column of objectMatrix
        v.multiplyScalar(distance);
        panOffset.add(v);
      };
    }();
    var pan = function() {
      var offset = new THREE.Vector3();
      return function pan(deltaX, deltaY) {
        var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;
        if (scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera) {
          var position = scope.object.position;
          offset.copy(position).sub(scope.target);
          var targetDistance = offset.length();
          targetDistance *= Math.tan((scope.object.fov / 2) * Math.PI / 180.0);
          panLeft(2 * deltaX * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix);
          panUp(2 * deltaY * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix);
        } else if (scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera) {
          panLeft(deltaX * (scope.object.right - scope.object.left) / scope.object.zoom / element.clientWidth, scope.object.matrix);
          panUp(deltaY * (scope.object.top - scope.object.bottom) / scope.object.zoom / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix);
        } else {
          console.warn('WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - pan disabled.');
          scope.enablePan = false;
        }
      };
    }();

    function dollyIn(dollyScale) {
      if (scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera) {
        scale /= dollyScale;
      } else if (scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera) {
        scope.object.zoom = Math.max(scope.minZoom, Math.min(scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom * dollyScale));
        scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
        zoomChanged = true;
      } else {
        console.warn('WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.');
        scope.enableZoom = false;
      }
    }

    function dollyOut(dollyScale) {
      if (scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera) {
        scale *= dollyScale;
      } else if (scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera) {
        scope.object.zoom = Math.max(scope.minZoom, Math.min(scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom / dollyScale));
        scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
        zoomChanged = true;
      } else {
        console.warn('WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.');
        scope.enableZoom = false;
      }
    }

    function handleMouseDownRotate(event) {
      rotateStart.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    function handleMouseDownDolly(event) {
      dollyStart.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    function handleMouseDownPan(event) {
      panStart.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    function handleMouseMoveRotate(event) {
      rotateEnd.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      rotateDelta.subVectors(rotateEnd, rotateStart);
      var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;
      rotateLeft(2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed);
      rotateUp(2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed);
      rotateStart.copy(rotateEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleMouseMoveDolly(event) {
      dollyEnd.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      dollyDelta.subVectors(dollyEnd, dollyStart);
      if (dollyDelta.y > 0) {
        dollyIn(getZoomScale());
      } else if (dollyDelta.y < 0) {
        dollyOut(getZoomScale());
      }
      dollyStart.copy(dollyEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleMouseMovePan(event) {
      panEnd.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      panDelta.subVectors(panEnd, panStart);
      pan(panDelta.x, panDelta.y);
      panStart.copy(panEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleMouseUp(event) {}

    function handleMouseWheel(event) {
      if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        dollyOut(getZoomScale());
      } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        dollyIn(getZoomScale());
      }
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleKeyDown(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case scope.keys.UP:
          pan(0, scope.keyPanSpeed);
          scope.update();
          break;
        case scope.keys.BOTTOM:
          pan(0, -scope.keyPanSpeed);
          scope.update();
          break;
        case scope.keys.LEFT:
          pan(scope.keyPanSpeed, 0);
          scope.update();
          break;
        case scope.keys.RIGHT:
          pan(-scope.keyPanSpeed, 0);
          scope.update();
          break;
      }
    }

    function handleTouchStartRotate(event) {
      rotateStart.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    }

    function handleTouchStartDolly(event) {
      var dx = event.touches[0].pageX - event.touches[1].pageX;
      var dy = event.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[1].pageY;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      dollyStart.set(0, distance);
    }

    function handleTouchStartPan(event) {
      panStart.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
    }

    function handleTouchMoveRotate(event) {
      rotateEnd.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
      rotateDelta.subVectors(rotateEnd, rotateStart);
      var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;
      rotateLeft(2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed);
      rotateUp(2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed);
      rotateStart.copy(rotateEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleTouchMoveDolly(event) {
      var dx = event.touches[0].pageX - event.touches[1].pageX;
      var dy = event.touches[0].pageY - event.touches[1].pageY;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      dollyEnd.set(0, distance);
      dollyDelta.subVectors(dollyEnd, dollyStart);
      if (dollyDelta.y > 0) {
        dollyOut(getZoomScale());
      } else if (dollyDelta.y < 0) {
        dollyIn(getZoomScale());
      }
      dollyStart.copy(dollyEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleTouchMovePan(event) {
      panEnd.set(event.touches[0].pageX, event.touches[0].pageY);
      panDelta.subVectors(panEnd, panStart);
      pan(panDelta.x, panDelta.y);
      panStart.copy(panEnd);
      scope.update();
    }

    function handleTouchEnd(event) {}

    function onMouseDown(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      switch (event.button) {
        case scope.mouseButtons.ORBIT:
          if (scope.enableRotate === false) return;
          handleMouseDownRotate(event);
          state = STATE.ROTATE;
          break;
        case scope.mouseButtons.ZOOM:
          if (scope.enableZoom === false) return;
          handleMouseDownDolly(event);
          state = STATE.DOLLY;
          break;
        case scope.mouseButtons.PAN:
          if (scope.enablePan === false) return;
          handleMouseDownPan(event);
          state = STATE.PAN;
          break;
      }
      if (state !== STATE.NONE) {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
        scope.dispatchEvent(startEvent);
      }
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      switch (state) {
        case STATE.ROTATE:
          if (scope.enableRotate === false) return;
          handleMouseMoveRotate(event);
          break;
        case STATE.DOLLY:
          if (scope.enableZoom === false) return;
          handleMouseMoveDolly(event);
          break;
        case STATE.PAN:
          if (scope.enablePan === false) return;
          handleMouseMovePan(event);
          break;
      }
    }

    function onMouseUp(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      handleMouseUp(event);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
      scope.dispatchEvent(endEvent);
      state = STATE.NONE;
    }

    function onMouseWheel(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false || scope.enableZoom === false || (state !== STATE.NONE && state !== STATE.ROTATE)) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      handleMouseWheel(event);
      scope.dispatchEvent(startEvent);
      scope.dispatchEvent(endEvent);
    }

    function onKeyDown(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false || scope.enableKeys === false || scope.enablePan === false) return;
      handleKeyDown(event);
    }

    function onTouchStart(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      switch (event.touches.length) {
        case 1:
          if (scope.enableRotate === false) return;
          handleTouchStartRotate(event);
          state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
          break;
        case 2:
          if (scope.enableZoom === false) return;
          handleTouchStartDolly(event);
          state = STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY;
          break;
        case 3:
          if (scope.enablePan === false) return;
          handleTouchStartPan(event);
          state = STATE.TOUCH_PAN;
          break;
        default:
          state = STATE.NONE;
      }
      if (state !== STATE.NONE) {
        scope.dispatchEvent(startEvent);
      }
    }

    function onTouchMove(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      switch (event.touches.length) {
        case 1:
          if (scope.enableRotate === false) return;
          if (state !== STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE) return;
          handleTouchMoveRotate(event);
          break;
        case 2:
          if (scope.enableZoom === false) return;
          if (state !== STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY) return;
          handleTouchMoveDolly(event);
          break;
        case 3:
          if (scope.enablePan === false) return;
          if (state !== STATE.TOUCH_PAN) return;
          handleTouchMovePan(event);
          break;
        default:
          state = STATE.NONE;
      }
    }

    function onTouchEnd(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      handleTouchEnd(event);
      scope.dispatchEvent(endEvent);
      state = STATE.NONE;
    }

    function onContextMenu(event) {
      if (scope.enabled === false) return;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel, false);
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);
    scope.domElement.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
    this.update();
  };
  THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create(THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype);
  THREE.OrbitControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControls;
  Object.defineProperties(THREE.OrbitControls.prototype, {
    center: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .center has been renamed to .target');
        return this.target;
      }
    },
    noZoom: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.');
        return !this.enableZoom;

      },
      set: function(value) {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.');
        this.enableZoom = !value;
      }
    },
    noRotate: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.');
        return !this.enableRotate;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.');
        this.enableRotate = !value;
      }
    },
    noPan: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.');
        return !this.enablePan;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.');
        this.enablePan = !value;
      }
    },
    noKeys: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.');
        return !this.enableKeys;

      },

      set: function(value) {

        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.');
        this.enableKeys = !value;
      }
    },
    staticMoving: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.');
        return !this.enableDamping;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.');
        this.enableDamping = !value;
      }
    },
    dynamicDampingFactor: {
      get: function() {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.');
        return this.dampingFactor;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        console.warn('THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.');
        this.dampingFactor = value;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your code snippets here? This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, I'm working on it. But adapting a code to be able to run as a snippet sure is a tough job, that's why I posted a link to the [repo](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test/tree/non-spaghetti)

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález There is a snippet here that runs but, somehow I can't get the key events to work here, I have no idea why. Same thing happens with jsfiddle so I guess the only way one can test it is by copying the codes and running it localy or clonning the [repo](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test/tree/non-spaghetti).